# ¿Cómo puedo dividir el contenido de un fichero en múltiples ficheros de acuerdo con unos patrones?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

¿Se puede mostrar primero un resultado y luego otro en un for con Awk?

Me explico: requiero separar datos dentro de un archivo pero solo tomando 1 y dejándolo en un archivo y luego el que viene en otro.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
for VRS_Listado in `cat Tablas/Listado.lst`
do

VRS_Cont=`awk '/CREATE/,/;/' "Tables.txt"`

echo "${VRS_Cont}" > Test/${VRS_Listado%.lst}.sql

done
```

la idea es traer una estructura y guardarla en un archivo y luego la que viene en otra, pero me guarda todo el contenido en diferentes archivos.

Y el contenido del .txt es:

```
   CREATE TABLE TablaUno
(
    ID_DOCVTA NUMERIC(38,0),
    NUMERO_NC NUMERIC(38,0),
    PERIODO BIGINT,
    NUMERO_DOC_FAC NUMERIC(38,0),
    CUENTA_PAGADORA NUMERIC(38,0),
    IMPUGNACION_COBRO CHARACTER VARYING(20),
    CUSTOMER_ID NUMERIC(38,0),
    ID_CICLO BIGINT,
    ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO CHARACTER VARYING(10),
    ID_ESTADO_VENTA BIGINT,
    USUARIO_CASO CHARACTER VARYING(90),
    USUARIO_NC CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    ID_SUCURSAL BIGINT,
    CREDIT_RZN_ID BIGINT,
    ID_TIPO_NEGOCIO BIGINT,
    FECHA_DE_EMISION_NC DATE,
    FECHA_VENCIMIENTO_FAC DATE,
    FECHA_INGRESO_SISTEMA_NC DATE,
    FECHA_EMISION_FAC DATE,
    FECHA_HORA DATE,
    FECHA_ACTUALIZACION DATE,
    MONTO_NETO_NC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_IVA_NC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_TOTAL_NC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_ORIGINAL_FAC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_CARGO NUMERIC(38,5),
    SMCARGOBRUTO NUMERIC(38,5),
    SMIVACARGO NUMERIC(38,5),
    SALDO_CARGO_FAC NUMERIC(38,5),
    VALIDO CHARACTER VARYING(10),
    FECHA_PROCESO DATE
)
DISTRIBUTE ON (ID_DOCVTA)
ORGANIZE ON (PERIODO, FECHA_PROCESO);
CREATE TABLE TablaDos
(
    ID_DOCVTA NUMERIC(38,0),
    NUMERO_NC NUMERIC(38,0),
    PERIODO BIGINT,
    NUMERO_DOC_FAC NUMERIC(38,0),
    CUENTA_PAGADORA NUMERIC(38,0),
    IMPUGNACION_COBRO CHARACTER VARYING(20),
    CUSTOMER_ID NUMERIC(38,0),
    ID_CICLO BIGINT,
    ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO CHARACTER VARYING(10),
    ID_ESTADO_VENTA BIGINT,
    USUARIO_CASO CHARACTER VARYING(90),
    USUARIO_NC CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    ID_SUCURSAL BIGINT,
    CREDIT_RZN_ID BIGINT,
    ID_TIPO_NEGOCIO BIGINT,
    FECHA_DE_EMISION_NC DATE,
    FECHA_VENCIMIENTO_FAC DATE,
    FECHA_INGRESO_SISTEMA_NC DATE,
    FECHA_EMISION_FAC DATE,
    FECHA_HORA DATE,
    FECHA_ACTUALIZACION DATE,
    MONTO_NETO_NC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_IVA_NC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_TOTAL_NC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_ORIGINAL_FAC NUMERIC(38,5),
    MONTO_CARGO NUMERIC(38,5),
    SMCARGOBRUTO NUMERIC(38,5),
    SMIVACARGO NUMERIC(38,5),
    SALDO_CARGO_FAC NUMERIC(38,5),
    VALIDO CHARACTER VARYING(10),
    FECHA_PROCESO DATE
)
DISTRIBUTE ON (ID_DOCVTA)
ORGANIZE ON (PERIODO, FECHA_PROCESO);
CREATE TABLE TablaTres
(
    PCS BIGINT,
    ID_PERIODO BIGINT,
    ID_TIPO_TRAFICO BIGINT,
    ID_PLAN BIGINT,
    VOLUMEN BIGINT,
    TOTAL_COST BIGINT,
    CANT_LLAMADA BIGINT,
    FECHA_MAX_LLAMADA DATE,
    DURACION_LLAMADA BIGINT,
    DIAS_LLAMADAS BIGINT
)
DISTRIBUTE ON (PCS);
```

la idea es que todo lo que está entre el bloque de  CREATE y el ; se guarde en un archivo, luego el siguiente bloque en otro y así hasta que se agote el contenido que leo en el `for`.

Comment: Si solucionaste el problema tú mismo, publica una respuesta. La zona de preguntas debe ser únicamente para eso, preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, estás intentando separar tu fichero de manera que cada `CREATE TABLE X` se guarde en un fichero `Test/X.sql`.

La estructura de tu fichero es fácil, pues todo el contenido pasará a formar parte de alguno de los archivos. Además, la información es secuencial, en el sentido que no hay que almacenar buffer ni nada: cuando dejas de leer para un archivo, pasas al siguiente.

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, la solución es tan fácil como:

```
awk '/CREATE TABLE \w/ {f=$NF ".sql"} {print > f}' fichero
```

Es decir: cuando lee un "CREATE TABLE X", recoge "X" y lo convierte en el nombre del fichero sobre el que se pasa a escribir.

Si quisieras validar que el nombre de la tabla aparece en el archivo Tables.txt, podrías cargarlas primero y luego ir comparando con el valor que aparece en "CREATE TABLE X":

```
awk 'FNR==NR {tablas[$0]=$0; next}
     /CREATE TABLE \w/ {if ($NF in tablas) f=$NF ".sql"}' tablas fichero
```

¡Lo que a todas luces parece poco óptimo es recorrer el fichero tantas veces como tablas contenga el fichero de tablas!